# On OS X in Safari, how to speed up or bypass the transition/animation in the 2-finger swipe to go back?

Tags: safari, macos

I like using this feature, but it's too slow for me now and I'm finding myself hitting the Delete key now because its faster. The Delete key doesn't animate the previous page in, it just goes back right away.

How can I speed up the swipe back animation, or skip it all together?

I'm using 10.10 (Yosemite).

Comment: Are you willing to use three fingers instead of two? There is no animation associated with the three-finger "swipe between pages".

Comment: For some reason, the 3-finger swipe has never worked for me. Maybe there's a config I'm missing. In any case, I prefer the 2-finger swipe.

Answer (score 2):

I realized I could user Better Touch Tool to do what I need. So, I'll post it as a work around.

In the Trackpad preferences, disable the Swipe between pages option.

In Better Touch Tool, add a trackpad gesture for Two Finger Swipe Right (I use natural scrolling) and associate it with the 3F Swipe Left (Page Back) action.

I also added a gesture for swiping left for page forward.